# Random log out of tty1 while typing

Tags: arch-linux, tty, troubleshooting, logout, virtual-consoles

I experienced a sudden log out from `tty1` where I run the i3 window manager.

While typing stuff, the screen went black, and in a matter of seconds I was back to the login screen (I use no login manager):

```
Arch Linux 5.15.10-arch1-1 (tty1)

enrico login:
```

It's actually the second time it happens. It happened a few days ago the first time, and I'm sure both then and now the log out happened *while* typing, but I have no idea what key combination might trigger a log out.

How can I troubleshoot this?

`last -F | head -2` shows

```
enrico   tty1                          Wed Dec 22 11:34:38 2021   still logged in
enrico   tty1                          Wed Dec 22 06:39:30 2021 - Wed Dec 22 11:34:26 2021  (04:54)
```

where the 11:34 event is when I logged back right after the strange log-out happened, whereas the previous event at 06:39 is when I originally logged in this morning.

Maybe I'm searching in the wrong place?

Comment: Do you automatically start i3 at login time? If so, how? This sounds like the i3 process died for some reason.

Comment: @Wieland, yes, I log in at the console, and then i3 starts up. For that purpose, I have `exec i3` in my `~/.xinitrc`. (I also have `xinput set-prop 11 "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1` in that file, but i think it's an old remnant of when I was using this file on a laptop; probably irrelevant to the problem I describe.)

Comment: Then I guess you also have something that automatically starts X at login (which would then do whatever's in `~/.xinitrc`), for example https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xinit#Autostart_X_at_login ? If so, do `If you would like to remain logged in when the X session ends, remove exec. `. If the problem then happens again, the screen will not be cleared and you might see an error message from i3. Or you might need to follow https://i3wm.org/docs/debugging.html to get to the bottom of what makes i3 quit.

Comment: @Wieland, yep, the last line in my `.bash_profile` is `[[ ! $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && exec startx`.